# Packing Rectangles IOI 95

Tags: algorithm, packing

I'm working my way through the [usaco](http://train.usaco.org/usacogate) training pages and came across this problem http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/ioi95/task/pack.html I don't understand the example input and output i.e. I cant find which of the 6 packing representations corresponds to the 4,10 and 5,8 lengths yielding the min total Area of 40.

Comment: hey @bneil did you understand how they have classified the packing rectangles into only 6 possible configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second from the right?

```
1222
1222
3333
3333
3333
4444
4444
4444
4444
4444
```

Third from the left?

```
33311
33322
33322
33322
44444
44444
44444
44444
```

Comment: How do those correspond? for the second from right, you are packing smaller rectangles ontop of the longest one. In the picture they seem to be next to each other? Similarly for the third from the left, I cant see how it corresponds to the picture.

Comment: Rotate both images in the link 90 degrees clockwise to obtain the above. `"any other layout can be obtained from a basic layout by rotation or reflection"`.

Comment: Ah I see I get the second example now thanks! but the first one still baffles me, isn't this how its suppposed to look and transform to? http://pastebin.com/TnZjGC6J